# Update entityManager()->getViewBuilder from 5 year old site?

Tags: theming, 9

I have a Drupal 8 module which hasn't been updated for 5 years.
I m trying to update to current version of Drupal.

The error I get is

```
Error: Call to undefined method Drupal::entityManager()
```

The code causing the error is below.

```
      $viewbuilder = \Drupal::entityManager()->getViewBuilder('paragraph');
      $data = $viewbuilder->view($paragraph);
      $array['#cache']['tags'][] = 'node:' . $node->id();
```

When I search one suggestions is to load through drupal service like below

```
\Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getViewBuilder('paragraph');
```

This gives a similar error, as does using EntityTypeManager

```
\Drupal::EntityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('paragraph');
```

How do I update this code?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! From the question, I understand that every time you call a `\Drupal` method, you get an error saying that method does not exist. Is that correct? Otherwise, what you do you mean with *a similar error*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View builders are now retrieved from the service [`entity_type.manager`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/entity_type.manager/10), which can be retrieved globally using [`\Drupal::entityTypeManager()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityTypeManager/10):

```php
\Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getViewBuilder('paragraph');
```

Or:

```php
\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('paragraph');
```

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 10, the code to get an entity view builder is used, for example, in [`BlockViewBuilderTest::testBasicRendering()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21tests%21src%21Kernel%21BlockViewBuilderTest.php/function/BlockViewBuilderTest%3A%3AtestBasicRendering/10).

```php
$builder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('block');
$output = $builder->view($entity, 'block');
```

The same code is used in [Drupal 9](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21tests%21src%21Kernel%21BlockViewBuilderTest.php/function/BlockViewBuilderTest%3A%3AtestBasicRendering/9) and [Drupal 8.9](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21tests%21src%21Kernel%21BlockViewBuilderTest.php/function/BlockViewBuilderTest%3A%3AtestBasicRendering/8.9.x).

Older code used [`Drupal::entityManager()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityManager/8.9.x), but as the documentation page says, that method has been deprecated and removed in Drupal 9. `\Drupal::entityTypeManager()` should be instead used in most cases.

If you get an error about `\Drupal::entityTypeManager()` being a non existing method, then the [core/lib/Drupal.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/9) file is probably corrupted.

The [*entity_field.manager*](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/entity_field.manager/9) is a completely different service and it is not the service you need to use. The class implementing it ([`EntityFieldManager`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFieldManager.php/class/EntityFieldManager/9)) does not define any `getViewBuilder()` method.